# Override jQuery ajax + tap in to the complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a bunch of $.ajax request in my app. I've got CSRF tokens I need to send with, and these tokens can expire after a short while. If they do, the ajax response returns a new token.

I want to redeclare $.ajax and check it's complete response, if returns my error with a new token. If so, I want to resend the original request, but now with the new token.

I've found here http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/ how I can redeclare a function, however I don't know how I can make it work for my situation: checking it's complete, possible resend everything as it was called to the function, and return the complete events etc. as normal.

Can anyone point me further in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `$.ajaxPrefilter`, it allows me to catch the response and make a new request using the originalOptions parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function has a myriad of options that should obviate the need for you to override its capabilities. For example, look into the "xhr", "xhrFiields" and "statusCode" options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I was looking for a central place to make it work for all ajax calls. I found what I was looking for because of your terms so thanks again.